# Javascript - Cannot Change Value of Select Using Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, I can set the select option in a dropdown list using javascript without a problem but when I execute the same code using an event listener the option does not change.

html:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="car">1</option>
    <option value="bike">2</option>
    <option value="cycle">3</option>
</select>
<button id = "button"  type = "button" class = "">Test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
const button = document.getElementById('button')
button.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    console.log('executed')
    document.getElementById('sel').value = 'bike'
})
```

Does not change the value eventhough executed is posted to the console. However, the following works and changes the option to 2

```
document.getElementById('sel').value = 'bike'
```

So how come document.getElementById('sel').value = 'bike' works when executed outside of the event listener but does not work inside of the event listener?

Comment: How is `button` defined?

Comment: Instead of showing individual pieces, can you make a runnable code snippet to demonstrate?

Comment: `id = "button",` should be `id='button'`, without the comma.

Comment: it is working as expected, if you set the `button` properly

Comment: <button id = "button",  type = "button" class = ""> Test </button> why do you have spaces and comma ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/10cal9e

Comment: your code is working fine with me on jsFiddle...

Comment: check your actual document code to see if your id (button) is not unique, i.e. your event listener is attached to something else before your button, and that triggers instead of your button.

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks to everyone who commented, you are correct it, the code does work fine in vanilla javascript. I am using materialcss as my styling theme and for whatever reason, when materialcss is applied, the event listener does not work. This is not the case when materialcss is no longer applied. I will post about this soon.